# A partition copied with cat can't be mounted

Tags: hard-drive, backup

Well some days ago my mac got broken, I had an Ubuntu on it and booted through it, first thing I did I copied mac partition to an external hard partition, something like this:

```
cat /dev/sda2 > /dev/sdc2
```

I was able to mount the sda2 partition in Ubuntu with hfsprogs, but I wasn't able to mount /dev/sdc2, I made a diff on two devices (with cmp) and they were just identical, now I erase sda2 and installed Yosemite again but I can't mount sdc2 even on mac (here it's disk2s2).

When I try to mount, verify or repair it, I get this error:

```
Invalid node structure
```

(this is the same error I got in Ubuntu for this partition), it's really weird cause I'm sure this partition is identical to the real one (and I was able to mount the real one in Ubuntu) I tried fixing it with DiskWarrior 5, it did its job without any error, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: I wouldn't have used `cat` in the manner you did and would have used `dd` to either copy the disk/partition to another disk/partition or created an image of the disk/partition to a file. Either `dd` usage would have resulted in an exact binary copy that would have been mountable and or restorable.  The cavauet with using `dd` alone is that the destination disk/partition has to be the same size or larger then the source partition as it copies the entire device not just the filesystem.

Comment: I don't get it, cat copies the partition bit by bit, after that I did a cmp on two devices and they were identical, a partition doesn't have magical information attached to it, all its information is the 0s and 1s it contains and cat copies these bits, I guess the problem is something with the guid of the partition or something like that (information stored in partition table, cause except those information everything is identical)

Answer (score 1):

`cat` is not an appropriate tool for copying volumes. It dumps files character by character. Yes, unix abstracts everything to a file, but it also distinguishes between character devices (files) and block devices (storage).

Wipe the partition and use dd, rsync, or a GUI tool like Carbon Copy Cloner to make a duplicate.

However, if I read your sequence correctly it looks like you made a copy and then wiped the original without verifying your copy. If so, time to get the backups out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I'm pretty sure that I've done the same for ext3/ext4/fat filesystems many times and it just worked. fortunately I have a timemachine backup made around 15 days ago but I just wanna know why it doesn't work with cat for hfs, I pretty sure that the cloned partition is identical to the original and I guess the problem is some information stored in partition table and I guess there's a way to recover this information.

Comment: ext and fat are much simpler filesystems and maybe copyable with cat. It's still not the tool for the job. The fact that you can't mount the copied volume says that something important got missed.

Comment: yeah and my question here is what's the missing part so that I can fix it, as I said I think it's something in partition table, maybe simply changing the uuid of the partition or something like that fixes it.

Comment: btw ext4 is not simpler than hfs+.

Comment: @Sassan, as paul mentioned and I second it, `cat` is not the appropriate tool for copying block devices in this context.  `dd` is what should have been used and you would not have had the issue you do.

Comment: @user3439894 thank you and paul for your replies, I certainly got it that I should use dd for cloning block devices, but my problem is not that I'm going to clone a HFS partition and I don't know what tool to use, my problem is that I already have a cloned hfs+ partition using cat and I wanna recover it.